# How do I get netbeans to stop handholding?

Tags: java, netbeans, autocomplete

I'm developing in netbeans 6.9.1 and sharing the resulting code with my team over git from the command line (no gui version).  Two behaviors of netbeans have become increasingly annoying:

1. Autocompletion.  I really don't like the way that netbeans handles closing parentheses.  Over the years, I've just developed the habit of closing these myself.  How can I turn off netbeans doing it for me?
2. Far nastier:  If I'm creating a gui component, I normally double-click the component to add the code.  That works for visual studio editing, and it's how I've been trained.  But it seems that such routines generated by netbeans are not editable by the user once they're created (ie, I can't edit anything but the body of the routines, delete them if I don't need them, or whatever).  That's a problem in a shared code environment, apparently (or at least, my team tells me they want to edit these lines and are getting stymied).

So how can I turn off these handholding features of netbeans?

Answer (score 6):

1)
Tools -> Options - > Code Completion Tab and turning off the last checkbox option will turn adding closing brackets off.

2) Sorry, I do not think there is an elegant way. Once you generate your GUI classes, you may edit the source using an external editor (this is how I did something in the past) - I do not think you can do something within netbeans to over-write generated GUI code.

Answer (score 2):

For first problem - use ring bearer's solution. 
For second one - if you right-click your component in visual editor, popup will show up - there you can choose "customize code" option. It will let you to change most of the options.